# Are relations built in to Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I know this is probably a stupid question, but I'm just reading the first chapter of Bratko Prolog Programming for artificial intelligence.

One of the first programs has clauses like

```
parent(ann, pat).
```

My question: parent, is that something that is built in to Prolog? Or is it something that is dealt with dynamically. Can I just go and invent things like:

```
dog(ann, pluto).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The simple answer is that you can just invent things like.

```
dog(ann, pluto).
```

These are simple FACTS that prolog will hold in its internal database. This is not a relational database. Just a collection of FACTS.

parent is not build into Prolog.

What make it interesting and useful is that you can create various rules to expand and confirm relationships for you.

```
grandparent(X,Z) :- parent(X,Y), parent(Y,Z).
```

Then you can ask

```
grandparent(ann,florence)
```

which will succeed it it is true, or fail if not.

Or you could ask

```
grandparent(ann,X)
```

and prolog should try and find and print out all grandparents of ann

or if you extend your FACTS base to include

```
mother(ann, jane)
father(ann, jim)
mother(jane, janice)
etc
etc
```

then

```
grandmother(X,Z) :-  mother(X,Y), mother(Y,Z).
```

can be deduced.

Suggest you keep on reading your book and all will be revealed.

Comment: While Prolog is not an RDBMS in the Postgres sense, it's not _not_ a relational database either. The distinction is blurry.

Comment: Correct. If you read my answer. That is what I said. I wanted to highlight that when prolog users talk about a fact or rules database they are not talking about what the rest of the world thinks of as a relational database. Some versions of Prolog have support packages for on-disk or in-memory B and Red & Black trees for high speed look-up, as Prolog 'database access' is slow. But because you can solve in +/- 8 hours something, that a human might take a week, you don't normally care.

Comment: I don't think Prolog database access is slow. The database is in-memory and indexed, after all.

Comment: Yes and No. Because its a facts database. It is often a only a double linked list of entries in a facts domain. Using 'Unification', any field or combination of fields can be used to satisfy a query. Normally not every field is indexed. So the unifier has to read every entry and compare if the bound fields match the fact fields. That is why many Prologs offer a B-Tree add-on so that you can add multiple indexes on your facts and their fields.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can invent things like that. It is called `clause`s, this type of clauses is called `fact`s. Facts are what your database is made of in Prolog. When you say

```
dog(ann, pluto).
```

you define relationship `dog` between two objects `ann` and `pluto`, these objects are called `atom`s and they are constant.
You can then query your database

```
| ?- dog(ann, pluto).
yes
```

Prolog will tell you if there is no defined relationship in database

```
| ?- dog(ann, oleg).
no
```